# Is there a workaround for the blocking that happens with Firebase Python SDK? Like adding a completion callback?

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, python-asyncio, firebase-admin

Recently, I have moved my REST server code in express.js to using FastAPI. So far, I've been successful in the transition until recently. I've noticed based on the firebase python admin sdk documention, unlike node.js, the python sdk is blocking. The documentation says [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#python):

> In Python and Go Admin SDKs, all write methods are blocking. That is, the write methods do not return until the writes are committed to the database.

I think this feature is having a certain effect on my code. It also could be how I've structured my code as well. Some code from one of my files is below:

```py
from app.services.new_service import nService
from firebase_admin import db
import json
import redis

class TryNewService:
  async def tryNew_func(self, request):
    # I've already initialized everything in another file for firebase
    ref = db.reference()
    r = redis.Redis()
    holdingData = await nService().dialogflow_session(request)
    fulfillmentText = json.dumps(holdingData[-1])
    body = await request.json()

    if ("user_prelimInfo_address" in holdingData):
      holdingData.append("session")
      holdingData.append(body["session"])
      print(holdingData)
      return(holdingData)
    else:
      if (("Default Welcome Intent" in holdingData)):
        pass
      else:
        UserVal = r.hget(name='{}'.format(body["session"]), key="userId").decode("utf-8")
        ref.child("users/{}".format(UserVal)).child("c_data").set({holdingData[0]:holdingData[1]})
        print(holdingData)
      return(fulfillmentText)
```

Is there any workaround for the blocking effect of using`ref.set()` line in my code? Kinda like adding a callback in node.js? I'm new to the asyncio world of python 3.

---

> Update as of 06/13/2020: So I added following code and am now getting a `RuntimeError: Task attached to a different loop`. In my second else statement I do the following:

```py
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
UserVal = r.hget(name='{}'.format(body["session"]), key="userId").decode("utf-8")
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as pool:
  result = await loop.run_in_executor(pool, ref.child("users/{}".format(UserVal)).child("c_data").set({holdingData[0]:holdingData[1]}))
  print("custom thread pool:{}".format(result))
```

With this new RuntimeError, I would appreciate some help in figuring out.

Comment: FYI: It's going to be the call to set() that blocks (since it does the I/O), not child().

Comment: @DougStevenson Yeah I understand that part. I'll change it in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run synchronous code inside an async coroutine, then the steps are:

1. loop = get_event_loop()
   Note: Get and not new. Get provides current event_loop, and new_even_loop returns a new one
2. await loop.run_in_executor(None, sync_method)

   - First parameter = None -> use default executor instance
   - Second parameter (sync_method) is the synchronous code to be called.

Remember that resources used by sync_method need to be properly synchronized:

- a) either using asyncio.Lock
- b) or using asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe function(see an example below)

Forget for this case about ThreadPoolExecutor (that provides a way to I/O parallelism, versus concurrency provided by asyncio).

You can try following code:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
UserVal = r.hget(name='{}'.format(body["session"]), key="userId").decode("utf-8")
result = await loop.run_in_executor(None, sync_method, ref, UserVal, holdingData)
print("custom thread pool:{}".format(result))
```

With a new function:

```
def sync_method(ref, UserVal, holdingData):
    result = ref.child("users/{}".format(UserVal)).child("c_data").set({holdingData[0]:holdingData[1]}))
    return result
```

Please let me know your feedback

Note: previous code it's untested. I have only tested next minimum example (using  pytest & pytest-asyncio):

```
import asyncio
import time

import pytest


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_1():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    delay = 3.0
    result = await loop.run_in_executor(None, sync_method, delay)
    print(f"Result = {result}")

def sync_method(delay):
    time.sleep(delay)
    print(f"dddd {delay}")
    return "OK"
```

### Answer @jeff-ridgeway comment:

Let's try to change previous answer to clarify how to use run_coroutine_threadsafe, to execute from a sync worker thread a coroutine that gather these shared resources:

1. Add loop as additional parameter in run_in_executor
2. Move all shared resources from sync_method to a new async_method, that is executed with run_coroutine_threadsafe

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
UserVal = r.hget(name='{}'.format(body["session"]), key="userId").decode("utf-8")
result = await loop.run_in_executor(None, sync_method, ref, UserVal, holdingData, loop)
print("custom thread pool:{}".format(result))

def sync_method(ref, UserVal, holdingData, loop):
    coro = async_method(ref, UserVal, holdingData)
    future = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(coro, loop)
    future.result()
async def async_method(ref, UserVal, holdingData)
    result = ref.child("users/{}".format(UserVal)).child("c_data").set({holdingData[0]:holdingData[1]}))
    return result
```

Note: previous code is untested. And now my tested minimum example updated:

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_1():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    delay = 3.0
    result = await loop.run_in_executor(None, sync_method, delay, loop)
    print(f"Result = {result}")

def sync_method(delay, loop):
    coro = async_method(delay)
    future = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(coro, loop)
    return future.result()

async def async_method(delay):
    time.sleep(delay)
    print(f"dddd {delay}")
    return "OK"
```

I hope this can be helpful

Comment: Accepting this as the answer as the previous answer has yet to answer my last comment + and this code raises no errors . Question: I'm trying to run the `await loop.run_in_executor(None, asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(sync_method))` code but I keep getting an error saying `TypeError: run_coroutine_threadsafe() missing 1 required positional argument: 'loop'`. I looked at the python3 documentation and it looks like I need to pass my event_loop as an argument. How do I pass the arguments to the `sync_method` function and the `event_loop` as an argument for `run_coroutine_threadsafe`? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Run blocking database calls on the event loop using a `ThreadPoolExecutor`. See https://medium.com/@hiranya911/firebase-python-admin-sdk-with-asyncio-d65f39463916

Comment: So I tried this but I'm getting a `RuntimeError: Task attached a different loop`. Is there a way I can get around this? Check out my edit to the original question with some new code

Comment: I'm not sure. But based on the error message I think you should somehow reuse the already existing event loop (the one used to run the enclosing function) rather than creating a new one with `new_event_loop()`.

Comment: Yeah I have tried that and it worked. When I follow your code from you medium post for `ref.get()` or `ref.set()` I keep getting a `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`. However when I run the code in the python interpreter I get a success (without using the `asyncio` library, knowing that it is blocking I/O)